# Why does Google Chrome change background opacity?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, webkit

I use the following CSS rule to set background color of `div`:

```
div {
    background-color: rgba(96, 96, 96, .1);
}
```

In Google Chrome v.42 in 'Computed' tab of Developer Tools I see this result `rgba(96, 96, 96, 0.0980392);`. I think, it looks like some web-kit optimization...

In FireFox v.36 computed background color equals to `rgba(96, 96, 96, 0.1)`

I've made a simple http://jsfiddle.net/sergfry/c7Lzf5v2/ that shows it in action.

So, can I prevent opacity changing in Google Chrome?

Thanks!

Comment: Probably just the IEEE floating point issue. Don't worry about it.

Comment: But if you check hex / rgb value of the output, its same #efefef as hex and rgb as 239.. The output is same as other browsers.. So dont mind about this :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As stated by Quentin, this is an IEEE floating point issue.

`0.1` doesn't actually exist in decimal floating point technically simply due to the way that binary works.

`0.1` is one-tenth, or 1/10. To show it in binary, divide binary 1 by binary 1010, using binary long division:

[image]

As you can see, `0.1` in binary is `0.0001100110011....0011` and it will keep repeating `0011` on the end to infinity.

Browsers will pick and choose the closest available point to `0.1` and use that as the opacity instead. Some will go over and some will go under.

FireFox i would guess it just showing the human readable version but in reality, its really using a computer usable floating point.

As an example:

```
body {
    color: rgba(0,0,0,0.1); // actually 0.0980392
    opacity: 0.1; // actually 0.100000001490116
}
```

Two completely different values for exactly the same floating point.

This floating point issue can actually be replicated elsewhere within browsers using other languages such as Javascript. Javascript numbers are always 64 bit floating point (which i believe CSS is as well). This is more commonly known as Double-precision floating point. PHP also uses double-precision floating points.

64 bit floating point numbers are as you could guess, stored in 64 bits, where the number (the fraction) is stored in bits 0 to 51, the exponent in bits 52 to 62, and the sign in bit 63.

This causes problems down the line as it means integers are only counted as accurate up to 15 decimal points and can really only calculate up to 17 decimal points.

This means that numbers can round up very easily or may just not be stored correctly.

```
var x = 999999999999999;  // x = 999999999999999
var y = 9999999999999999; // y = 10000000000000000
```

The arithmetic for floating points can also be out of alignment by quite a lot in places as well. As I've shown above; `0.1` in decimal isn't actual `0.1` but `0.000110011...` and so on. This means some basic maths can be completely wrong.

```
var x = 0.2 + 0.1; // x = 0.30000000000000004
```

You end up having to confuse the system to get the number you actually want. This can be done by `*` the number by `10` and then dividing it to get your actual wanted result.

```
var x = (0.2 * 10 + 0.1 * 10) / 10; // x = 0.3
```

Precision within computers floating point is very difficult and is even more difficult when there are multiple different implementations (or browsers) trying to do their best for speed and displaying the information they're given correctly.

There are quite a few different pieces of information regarding floating points and what the CSS processor (or JS as I expect may calculations will be the same) may be trying to achieve.

- [Exploring Binary - Why 0.1 does not exist](http://www.exploringbinary.com/why-0-point-1-does-not-exist-in-floating-point/)
- [Javascript Numbers](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_numbers.asp)
- [Wikipedia - IEEE floating point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point)
- [Wikipedia - Double-precision floating point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, Stewartside!